# Is it possible not to jump to the top of the page on form submit?

Tags: php, html

> FIXED, Wrapping the input tag with an anchor tag around it seemed to
>   have worked.

The question could sound a bit confusing, let me elaborate.

I have made a mail form with PHP. This form is all the way at the bottom of the page.
When I click send (this is an input tag), if there are errors, it will display them above the form.

But when you click on send the page will first go back to the top and you have to scroll all the way down to see if you have made any errors.

So is it possible to keep the page from jumping back the the start?

Comment: Posting some code would have helped. what i think is,you are redirecting the page to itself at the end. So, it is loading again.

Comment: @Rick If one of these answers helped you should accept it by clicking the tick icon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have a page anchor on the form and point at that anchor in the form action, something like this should do that for you.

```
<form  action="someformaction.php#form-anchor" id="form-anchor">
</form>
```

Now when the form is submitted it should move the page down to where that anchor is.

Comment: An `id` on the form would work just as well, and be far more semantically accurate than an empty `<a>` tag.

Comment: Ok cool, I wasn't aware that you could link to an id with an anchor tag. I'll update my answer. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it, you are submitting a normal form which in turn sends the email.

You can possibly put an anchor at the bottom of the page and have the action of the form point to it, so that your user will open up on that part of the page, or you could submit via a ajax instead which will not cause a page reload. Here are a [bunch of tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=submit+form+via+ajax&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs) you could adapt to your code.

Comment: yes, its a normal form.
the anchor doesnt work i will look into the tutorials.
Thanks

Comment: @Rick You did place an achor tag just above the form and pointed the form action to it - as per sabre's answer below?