# Anchor tag in PHP email form

Tags: php, html, css

Can you please help anybody?

I have made a mail form with PHP. This form is all the way at the bottom of the page. When I click send (this is an input tag), if there are errors, it will display them above the form.

But when you click on send the page will first go back to the top and you have to scroll all the way down to see if you have made any errors.

So is it possible to keep the page from jumping back the the start?

I know it was been solved many times e.g. here [Is it possible not to jump to the top of the page on form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950509/is-it-possible-not-to-jump-to-the-top-of-the-page-on-form-submit/11950608#11950608)
but enclose this code  it will still scrool above contact section in the portfolio section......
my page svejdamartin.com
Do you have any ideas ?

```
<footer>
  <section id="contact">                   
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div id="fourth">
          <h1>Contact Form</h1>
          <p>Please, do not hesitate to contact me if you want to get more information.</p>
           <?php
             if (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) { // ne POST ale GET //
               echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you, I will be in touch</div>'; // toto se vypise po odeslani vzkazu //

             } else {  //tento tag konci az na konci formulare !!! Otevrel jsem tam php a ukoncil tento else //
               if (empty ($errors) === false) { // tohle php vypisuje upozornovaci hlasky primo nad formularem //
                 echo '<ul>';
                 foreach($errors as $error) {
                   echo '<li>', $error, '</li>';            
                 }
                 echo '</ul>';
               }           
             ?>
             <form id="form-anchor" method="post" action="index.php#form-anchor">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" <?php if (isset($_POST['name']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['name']), '"'; } ?>>                                       
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" <?php if (isset($_POST['email']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['email']), '"'; } ?>>                                       
               </div>                                                                        
               <div class="form-group">
                 <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="message...."><?php if (isset($_POST['message']) === true) { echo strip_tags($_POST['message']); } ?></textarea>                                       
               </div>
               <div class="checkbox">
                 <label>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="check">I am human
                 </label>
               </div>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="send message">                                   
             </form>
             <?php
             }
           ?>
         </div>    
       </div>
     </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why the hell you didn't use google reCaptcha? https://www.google.com/recaptcha Do you think your checkbox "I am human" will prevent spammers in spamming your inbox?

Comment: Thanks, I didn t know that , I am still beginner in these things.

Comment: You are welcome. Implementation of google reCaptcha will take you max. 5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the page ends in the portfolio section instead of contacts is because the browser looks for the `#fourth` anchor before the images in the portfolio are loaded.

So the browser correctly positions the page but then the contact form moves down because of the animation.

One way to fix this is to define the height of the `#imag` div so that it is already the size that the images will be.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, I believe that it is the problem, it does make a sence. I tried to in CSS #imag height 3100px and it didn t help. You write about one way, please do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot upload my css , It help. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use JavaScript to go to the anchor when the page loads after the form has been submitted using `echo '<script>location.hash = "#form-anchor";</script>';`

```
<footer>
<section id="contact">                   
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div id="fourth">

                            <h1>Contact Form</h1>

                            <p>Please, do not hesitate to contact me if you want to get more information.</p>

                                   <?php
                                    if (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {    // ne POST ale GET //
                                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you, I will be in touch</div>';
                                        echo '<script>location.hash = "#form-anchor";</script>'; // toto se vypise po odeslani vzkazu //

                                    } else {  //tento tag konci az na konci formulare !!! Otevrel jsem tam php a ukoncil tento else //
                                    if (empty ($errors) === false) { // tohle php vypisuje upozornovaci hlasky primo nad formularem //
                                        echo '<ul>';
                                        foreach($errors as $error) {
                                            echo '<li>', $error, '</li>';            
                                        }
                                        echo '</ul>';
                                        echo '<script>location.hash = "#form-anchor";</script>';
                                    }    
                                    ?>

                            <form id="form-anchor" method="post" action="index.php">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" <?php if (isset($_POST['name']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['name']), '"'; } ?>>                                       
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                     <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" <?php if (isset($_POST['email']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['email']), '"'; } ?>>                                       
                                 </div>                                                                        
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="message...."><?php if (isset($_POST['message']) === true) { echo strip_tags($_POST['message']); } ?></textarea>                                       
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="check">I am human
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="send message">                                   
                            </form>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>

                      </div>    
                 </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I tried it and the effect is the same..

Answer (score 0):

I have visited your page, i found that, when i fill the form but not selecting the 'I am human' checkbox and press send message URL shows '#fourth' which is address to anchor tag for contact. but i found one problem in this, when we click on other link like home or about, the page first navigates to the section and then URL changes, it directly means just passing link address will not navigate you to your page section as javascript events are also involved in this as shown in attached screen shot [image: screen shot], so i suggest you to recall the javascript function shown in screen shot with the required target parameter, as

```
function setSection(target, e) {
    e.preventDefault()


    var $target = $(target);

    //sroll and show hash
    $('html,body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });

    // scroll and do not show hash
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1000, 'swing');
});
}
```

and call this function when contact form submits.

Comment: Thank you for your time to check my web i will solve javascript again . Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

The form is designed to post to an element within the form. Change action="index.php#form-anchor" to  action="index.php"